# Parsing error: Unexpected token => when trying to deploy firebase cloud function. I couldn't find any answers on here

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
exports.sendInvite = functions.firestore
  .document("invites/{phoneNumber}")
  .onCreate(async (doc) => { //error is here I assume
    const from = "+<mynumber>";
    const to = doc.data().phoneNumber;

    const text = "You can join the club now";

    return client.messages.create(from, to, text);
  });
```

my .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};
```

My firebase cloud function is throwing this error `Parsing error: Unexpected token =>`.
Does anyone know why this is happening? I am using javascript btw not TS.
[image]

Comment: What Node version are you using?

Comment: @Phil node version 15.8.0 and npm version 6.14.11

Comment: Where do you see the error? Any chance you could provide a screenshot to show context?

Comment: @Phil yes i will edit my post and add a screen shot

Comment: @Phil screen shot should be available now

Comment: That's a linting error. Check your ESLint configuration

Comment: @Phil this is my .eslintrc.js file ```module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};``` oh jesus that did not format well

Comment: Try adding `ecmaVersion: 8` to `env`.

Comment: @Adam unfortunately it says ecmaVersion is not a known key

Comment: My fault, I meant to say add it under `parserOptions`, not `env`. Try that.

Comment: @Adam okay now im getting different linter errors referring to number of spaces used to indent. Oh lawd haha

Comment: Ok, the `ecmaVersion` setting fixes your main issue though, so I'll create an answer for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arrow functions are an ES6 feature, but here you have an *async* arrow function.

Async functions in general are an **ES8** (or **2017**) feature. Therefore you need to specify the following setting at the root of your config:

```js
parserOptions: {
  ecmaVersion: 8 // or 2017
}
```

This will let the parser know to expect the `=>` token after `async` is used.

Comment: To clarify: you need to add this to your .eslintrc.js file.

Answer (score 8):

Go to your file packages.json and change the line to this one.

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint",
    ...
},
```

The generated version it will contain "eslint ."

Comment: This stops it from checking your code. It wont show any errors if you do this.

Answer (score -2):

in VScode go to settings.json  and enter the following keyword

"eslint.options":{"settng":true}

check here:
https://youtu.be/I8D0BObBXyg