# firebase Function async cant be used

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-functions

previously (about a year plus ago), I have made an onCreate firebase Function like this with "async". It appears, this function has some changes (deprecated but still exist)

```
exports.createDocu = functions.firestore
  .document(`docu/{docuId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
```

now snap changes to snapshot. Below works.

```
exports.createDocu = functions.firestore
    .document("docu/{docuId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
```

However, I cant put async like below.

```
exports.createDocu = functions.firestore
    .document("docu/{docuId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
```

It will cause

```
13:41  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>
```

I saw this https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions, is it using "then" ?

The question is how can I support my previous implementation with the current Firebase Function to work with async ?

My current version

```
% node -v
v14.17.1
% npm -v
6.14.13
```

Comment: "I cant put async" Why not? What's keeping you from doing so?

Comment: I updated the description. it causes, 13:41  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Comment: It seems like either your node or (more likely) eslint is not configured to recognize ES8/2017. See some the top results from https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+functions+error+Parsing+error%3A+Unexpected+token+%22%3D%3E%22, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/66431847/209103

Comment: Since I have about 2 dozen Cloud functions ALL working with async, I don't think the problem is with firestore... also, there is LITERALLY no difference between ```exports.createDocu = functions.firestore
  .document(`docu/{docuId}`)
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {``` and ```exports.createDocu = functions.firestore
    .document("docu/{docuId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {``` - just changing what *your* code names the first argument has no other affect, so there is something wrong *outside* of what you show...

Comment: for example:
```
export default functions.firestore
  .document(
    "/Path/{to}/Desired/{documents}"
  )
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {``` - in use, right now.

Comment: I am using whatever the latest firebase function is setting me up (started few days ago only) and migrating to there. ok, maybe its Lint since its so strict now. I am looking at your link, how can I configure the parseOptions to ecmaVersion 8, currently this is how it looks like on .eslintrc.js (do I put it here ?)https://gist.github.com/axilaris/17a55af516f0ed31bab5848db6cbeb5e

Comment: it worked, can you put the eslint solution (parseOptions to ecmaVersion 8). why would firebase not fix this. hmm